# I can't seem to get express to bind to all interfaces or access it from outside a container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express, ip

You may find it easier to clone this ***MINIMAL EXAMPLE*** code from this repository: https://github.com/dscottboggs/express-problem-example

The repository contains exactly what is listed below and is **provided only for convenience**!

As stated in the title of the question the issue is accessing the express application from outside the container.

### Index.js

```js
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({hello: "world"}))

app.listen({port: 12345, host: '0.0.0.0'}, () => console.log('ready'))
```

I have also tried `app.listen(12345)` and `app.listen(12345, '0.0.0.0')` as you can see in this [commit history](https://github.com/dscottboggs/express-problem-example/commits/main/index.js).

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /project
ADD package.json yarn.lock /project/
RUN yarn
EXPOSE 12345
ADD index.js /project/
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "test-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "what's the deal",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

### Steps to reproduce:

- Running `node index.js`, then `curl localhost:12345/`, a response is recieved
  right away.
- Run this...

  ```
  docker build -t test-express .
  container_id="$(docker run -d test-express)"
  docker exec $container_id curl localhost:12345/
  ```

  ...and there will be an immediate response
- With the container still running, run

  ```
  ip_addr=$(docker inspect $container_id  --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress }}"
  curl $ip_addr:12345
  ```

  ... and it will hang forever.

Please note the presence of the specified (but default) value of the host
binding.

Comment: It appears that this is only happening when using Docker Desktop on MacOS. Doing the same thing on a linux VM does not reproduce the issue. I'll leave the question here for posterity but I think I'm just going to be working out of a VM.

Comment: Map the port to a host port with `docker run -d -p 23456:12345 test-express` and then access the container from the host using `curl localhost:23456`.

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address is pretty much useless.  There's never a reason to look it up.  Among other scenarios, it's unusable if you're using Docker Desktop (on any host OS).  @HansKilian has the right answer.